# Windows 8.1 update is not showing

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, 64-bit

I have all the updates needed for windows 8.1 and I still cannot find the update to the 8.1 in the app store. Why can't I get the update?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get it from the store. Following the instructions on the Microsoft site here:

1. On the Start screen, tap or click Store to open the Windows Store.
   Doing this first will make it so that you can see the progress of
   the installation once it starts.
2. After opening the Store, return to this page.
3. Click to download Windows 8.1 from the Windows Store.

You can also get this update on CD, should you want to go out and purchase it. Should you need more help from there, there is a full guide to [upgrading here.](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2054670/upgrading-to-windows-8-1-your-new-os-survival-guide.html)

Comment: Question not answered. The upgrade is not showing in the store. So "go to store" is not helpful.

Comment: @Lenne http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/why-can-t-find-update-store

Comment: Not working either.